# How to use yarn with private npm registry in Sonatyoe Nexus OSS?

Tags: npm, nexus, yarnpkg

I ve setup the nexus oss 3 and it looks cool. All my projects are installed by using yarn because of the --pure-lockfile option.

Steps to reproduce the issue: 
1. Setup nexus oss 3 with a private npm registry (as in documentation)
2. Disable anonymous access from nexus oss 3 admin panel 
3. On a linux server with alpine try to yarn install --pure-lockfile (you must have a package that is hosted on the private repo in package.json) 
4. Does not work, return 401 error

I tried everything but i could not manage to make yarn to login to get those packages.

If i use npm install, it works.

Can someone tell me how to make yarn work nexus oss3 using the setup from above?

Comment: This is interesting. I'll give it a look tomorrow. AFAIK it should work.

Comment: I know it should, but for me it doesn t. I tried every auth method for npm, but yarn does not want to work :(

Comment: We're also thinking of using yarn and nexus 3. What happened with this?

Answer (score 5):

If `npm install` is working, then you must have login credentials and repository correctly defined.

1. Open terminal and run `npm login`, give your username and password for nexus account. This will create a file `~/.npmrc`. Open this file `nano ~/.npmrc`, output look like

`//<repository>:_authToken=NpmToken.<token>`

A dummy example:

`//test.server.com/repository/npm-group/:_authToken=NpmToken.123456-12345-12345-tok-en0onum`

2. Go to the project directory `cd <project_dir>`, create a new file `.yarnrc`, open it `nano .yarnrc`. Insert the following line, save and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) it.

`registry "<repository>"`

3. Create another file `.npmrc` in the same directory `<project_dir>`. Open, add the following line, save and exsit.

`registry=<repository>
always-auth=true
//<repository>:_authToken=NpmToken.<token>`

4. Delete the `.npmrc` at home directory `rm ~/.npmrc`.
5. Now you can download `node_modules` with `yarn` or `yarn install`.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with nexus 3 and use this configuration on my **.npmrc** file:

```
registry=https://your.nexus.com/repository/some-npm/
always-auth=true
/* basic-auth-token: your user:password in base64 */
_auth=<basic-auth-token>
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score -1):

The fact that your requests returns 401 (Unauthorized) means that you should supply credentials when connecting to Nexus.

It is far from being a nice solution but I got it working using
`yarn set registry https://user:pwd@your.nexus.host/nexus3/repository/npmjs/`

I use yarn 1.4.0 (release candidate). It should also work on 1.3.2, but I cannot test that because 1.3.2 has issues with HTTPS_PROXY env vars.